# how to submit two forms with different button in web page

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-models, django-forms

I created a submission form I used (one to one relation) to all fields except some fields which not related to one to one relation in models.py file and I used (one to many relations) to skills, version, last-used, experience. Now my question is how to send data to the database by click on the button add without refreshing page with using ajax and javascript.

[image]

My code is in views.py

```
def data1(request,id):
if request.method == 'GET':
    obj = username.objects.get(id=id)
    form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'data1.html', {'form': form, 'usernames': obj})
elif request.method == 'POST':
    obj = username.objects.get(id=id)
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        it_skills = request.POST['it_skills']
        version = request.POST['version']
        it_skills_last_used = request.POST['it_skills_last_used']
        experience= request.POST['experience']
        skills(it_skills=it_skills, version=version, it_skills_last_used=it_skills_last_used,experience=experience,uname=obj).save()
        #viewd=obj.Profiledata_set.all()
        #viewds=obj.skills_set.all()
        return render(request, 'data1.html', {'usernames': obj})
    return render(request, 'data1.html', {'usernames': obj})
```

And my javascript is

```js
<script>
    function insertdata(id)
        {
        alert("data")
        var itskill= $("[name='it_skills']").val();
        var version= $("[name='version']").val();
        var skilllastused= $("[name='it_skills_last_used']").val();
        var experience= $("[name='experience']").val();
        var data = {
              it_skills:itskill,
              version:version,
              it_skills_last_used:skilllastused,
              experience:experience
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/data1/"+id+"/",
            data:JSON.stringify(data);
            Content-Type: 'application/json ;charset =utf-8',
            dataType:'json',
            async:false
            success: function (msg) {
              alert('Data Saved');
            }
            error: function (status) {
              alert('Insertion Failed');
            }
        });
        }

  </script>
```

In Html,

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="div_id_country_work_authorization" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_country_work_authorization" class=" requiredField">Country work authorization<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class=""> <input type="text" name="country_work_authorization" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_country_work_authorization"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_preferred_roles" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_preferred_roles" class=" requiredField">Preferred roles<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class=""> <input type="text" name="preferred_roles" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_preferred_roles"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_preferred_job_type" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_preferred_job_type" class=" requiredField">Preferred job type<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class=""> <input type="text" name="preferred_job_type" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_preferred_job_type"> </div>
    </div>
    
    

    <div class="form-row">
            <div id="div_id_it_skills" class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                <label for="id_it_skills" class=" requiredField">It skills<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
                <div class=""> <input type="text" name="it_skills" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_it_skills"> </div>
            </div>
            <div id="div_id_version" class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                <label for="id_version" class=" requiredField">Version<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
                <div class=""> <input type="number" name="version" step="any" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_version"> </div>
            </div>
            <div id="div_id_it_skills_last_used" class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                <label for="id_it_skills_last_used" class=" requiredField">last used<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
                <div class=""> <input type="text" name="it_skills_last_used" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_it_skills_last_used"> </div>
            </div>
            <div id="div_id_experience" class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                <label for="id_experience" class=" requiredField">Experience<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
                <div class=""> <input type="text" name="experience" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_experience"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button onclick="insertdata()" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            </div>
    </div>






    <div id="div_id_gender" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_gender" class=" requiredField">Gender<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class=""> <input type="text" name="gender" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_gender"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_date_of_birth" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_date_of_birth" class=" requiredField">Date of birth<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class=""> <input type="text" name="date_of_birth" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_date_of_birth"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_marital_status" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_marital_status" class=" requiredField">Marital status<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class=""> <input type="text" name="marital_status" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_marital_status"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_languages" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_languages" class=" requiredField">Languages<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class=""> <input type="text" name="languages" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_languages"> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

please help me thanks in advance